# How to acquire schema lock is one already exists?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, personal-geodatabase, schema-locks

I'm trying to delete a feature class from a feature dataset or to add a field to it, but I keep getting an error message (pics attached below). I have imported a geometric network I've created from one PGDB to another. However couldn't add any fields. I'm receiving the following error:

[image]

Than I planned to delete the feature classes that were imported - I've received the following error:

[image]

I have the feeling that both errors are related but couldn't figure out the problem from ESRI help or from other posts in gis.stackexchange.

Comment: Have you tried closing *all* ESRI applications? Then only start the one where you will do the editing. If no changes, also try to restart your computer.

Comment: It worked (deleting), Thanks . I understand that it is just a bug?

Comment: Sometimes there are (legit) locks on files you try to edit, because they are open in, say, ArcCatalog. 
However, it happens that the locks are not properly released when the file is no longer open in that other application. This happens to me almost every day, and the fastest solution is to close all applications.

Comment: Once you add a feature class to a project, even if you immediately remove it, it is likely it is locked until that thread of ArcMap is closed.  If the feature class is in a feature dataset with a topology it is possible all the dataset features will similarly be locked.  The separate program version of ArcCatalog can lock or suffer from locked files in ArcMap too but the ArcCatalog tab in ArcMap will in many cases allow you to do things like delete or rename features even when they are still in ArcMap.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Close all ESRI applications. Then only start the one where you will do the editing (eg. Arcmap).

This will release all locks that are on your data from other applications, which are interfering with your data manipulation.

If it still doesn't work, also try to restart your computer.

Comment: Sometimes Arcmap has a hung process, perhaps after a failed geoprocessing tool, even if there are no visible windows. After you close all Arcgis applications, run Windows *Task Manager* and open the *Processes* tab. Force close any `ArcMap.exe` or `ArcCatalog.exe` processes. (*ArcGISConnection.exe* and *ArcGISCacheMgr.exe* are ok to leave running).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Arcgis maybe corrupted or need to update latest service packs or patches

Comment: My version just been updated to 10.2 few days ago

Comment: I had same problem while released arcgis 10. After sometime I have updated some patches and then problem has been solved.

Comment: Please check in your GEO - Database is there any topology rules added with that feature class or any link between two feature class.

Comment: I havn't found any topology rules. I only planarized the layer using the advanced editing toolbar. What do you mean by link between feature classes?

Comment: Means that relationship feature class

Comment: Does creating a geometric network form a relationship (let's say between lines and nodes)?

Comment: yes, Please try to delete field without nodes feature-class in separate geodatabase.

Comment: I can't do it now since I've already deleted those feature classes after restarting the program. I can't re-construct the problem...

Comment: Can post jpg for your geodatabase structure.

Comment: Like the second one that I had posted above?

Comment: yes sorry.In that geodatabase have you deleted Neve_not_net_junctions feature class tried.In ArcMAP Please close Arccatalog and try maybe its work.

Comment: actually I've tried to delet both the junctions and roads feature classes (Neve_not_net_junctions, Neve_noy_roads). Both was un-edditable and gave me the same error while trying to delete them.

Comment: My final comment have you tried with Arctoolbox - delete field tool.if can't delete then feature class maybe corrupted.

Comment: Did not try - but will give it a try next time I have the problem. 10x

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11600/discussion-between-venug-and-dof1985)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to open Access table and delete unnecessary field or change data type PGDB to shape file and delete field.